# Convert to PDO regexp bind error

Tags: regex, pdo, bind

I'm trying to convert from mysql to using PDO. I'm stuck on this error. For the most part I got it working except when it comes to binding the variable.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in
```

Here is what I tried:

```
global $keyword;

$_link = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", "$username", "$password");

$_query = sprintf("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM PLD_ANINJA WHERE `Text` REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]',:keyword,'[[:>:]]') LIMIT %d,%d",
    SmartyPaginate::getCurrentIndex(), SmartyPaginate::getLimit());
$_query->bindParam(':keyword',$keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$_query->execute();
```

Here is what worked originally:

```
global $keyword;

$_query = sprintf("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM PLD_ANINJA WHERE `Text` REGEXP '[[:<:]]" . $keyword . "[[:>:]]' LIMIT %d,%d",
    SmartyPaginate::getCurrentIndex(), SmartyPaginate::getLimit());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to call a PDO method on a string, not a PDO statement object. You need to call `$_link->prepare()`.

```
$_query = $_link->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM PLD_ANINJA WHERE `Text` REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]',:keyword,'[[:>:]]') LIMIT :start,:count");
$_query->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$_query->bindValue(':start', SmartyPaginate::getCurrentIndex());
$_query->bindValue(':count', SmartyPaginate::getLimit());
$_query->execute();
```